# Brownian motion property on interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Say $B$ is a Brownian motion. Knowing that for some constant $a\gt0$
$$P(\sup_{[0,n]} |B|\leq 1) \leq e^{-{an}}$$
how can I deduce that

$$P\left(\sup_{[0,1]} |B| \leq \frac{1}{n}\right)\leq e^{-{an^2}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rewriting the inequality for $n' \equiv n^2$, we have that $$ \mathbb P(\sup_{[0,n^2]} |B|\leq 1) \leq e^{-{an^2}} \tag1$$
Now, if $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a Brownian Motion, then $W \equiv \left(nB_{t/n^2}\right)_{t\ge0}$ [is also a Brownian Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Self-similarity) for all $n >0$. Therefore, applying inequality $(1)$ to the process $W$, we get :
$$\begin{align}\mathbb P(\sup_{[0,n^2]} |W|\leq 1) &= \mathbb P(\sup_{t\in[0,n^2]} n|B_{t/n^2}|\leq 1)\\
&=\mathbb P\left(\sup_{t\in[0,n^2]} |B_{t/n^2}|\leq \frac1 n\right)\\ 
&=\mathbb P\left(\sup_{s\in[0,1]} |B_{s}|\leq \frac1 n\right) \\
&\le e^{-{an^2}} \end{align} $$